# sphinx speech recognition delay

Tags: java, cmusphinx

I am using the open source sphinx sdk to do some voice recognition.  I am currently running the HelloWorld example.  However response is very sluggish,  it takes several attempts to recognize a word, and sometimes it recognizes it but takes a little to output what I have said.  Any ideas how to improve this?  Also when I change the grammer file it doesn't update and recognize my new words.

Thanks

Comment: how fast is your CPU? speech recognition takes a lot of processing time

Answer (score 1):

- Basically you can use `Sphinx` in several configurations. If you know the pattern of the voice that you have to recognize then you can use the configuration with `custom grammar`.
- In that configuration its having higher response rate than normal configuration, since it only listen for predefine words with pre-define pattern. (a Grammar)
- You can define your own grammar file by following the JSGF standards. ([more](http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/))

**Sample Configuration**

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setAcousticModelPath(ACOUSTIC_MODEL);
configuration.setDictionaryPath(DICTIONARY_PATH);
configuration.setGrammarPath(GRAMMAR_PATH);
configuration.setUseGrammar(true);
configuration.setGrammarName("mygrammar");

LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
```

**Sample Grammar File**

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar mygrammar;
public <COMMON_COMMAND> = [please] turn (on | off) lighs;
```